# How to compress text using python zlib and decompress using java zlib?

Tags: java, python, zlib, compression

I want to compress text using python zlib, 
and send the compressed text via Apache Thrift,
and finally I have decompress the compressed text in Java.

But I don't know how to do this. I cannot find any module, working like python zlib in Java. I need some help!

In [1]: import zlib

In [2]: text = 'abcd가나다라1234'

In [3]: comp_text = zlib.compress(text)

In [4]: print type(comp_text)

In [5]: print comp_text

xKLJNyµ¡ඓ؝K^Нchdlw

... send comp_text via Thrift as string ...
... decompress comp_text using Java ...

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/Deflater.html ?

Comment: By the way, every time you print binary data directly, you have taken one step closer to hell.

Answer (score 1):

Java's [`Inflater`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/zip/Inflater.html) class will decompress what has been compressed by Python's `zlib.compress()`.